# In Isaiah 5:2, what is the function of the tower, and how is it prophetically significant?

Tags: isaiah

> [Isaiah 5:1-7 NASB20] (1) Let me sing now for my beloved A song of my beloved about His vineyard. My beloved had a vineyard on a fertile hill. (2) He dug it all around, cleared it of stones, And planted it with the choicest vine. **And He built a tower in the middle of it,** And also carved out a wine vat in it; Then He expected [it] to produce [good] grapes, But it produced [only] worthless ones. (3) "And now, you inhabitants of Jerusalem and people of Judah, Judge between Me and My vineyard. (4) "What more was there to do for My vineyard that I have not done in it? Why, [when] I expected [it] to produce [good] grapes did it produce worthless ones? (5) "So now let Me tell you what I am going to do to My vineyard: I will remove its hedge and it will be consumed; I will break down its wall and it will become trampled ground. (6) "I will lay it waste; It will not be pruned nor hoed, But briars and thorns will come up. I will also command the clouds not to rain on it." (7) For the vineyard of the LORD of armies is the house of Israel, And the people of Judah are His delightful plant. So He waited for justice, but behold, [there was] bloodshed; For righteousness, but behold, a cry for help.

What does building a tower add to this prophecy?

Might it be related to:

> [Isaiah 5:8 NASB20] (8) Woe to those who attach house to house [and] join field to field, Until there is no more room, **And you alone are a landowner in the midst of the land!**

Answer (score 2):

Such "towers" served two essential functions: (1) as a watchtower for general protection of the facility, and, (2) office and residence for personnel and storage for equipment and tools.  Further, it probably also housed the actual wine press but that is debatable as these were sometimes outdoors.

Benson offers these helpful comments:

> **And he built a tower in the midst of it** — As edifices, termed towers by the Jews, were erected in vineyards, containing, as Bishop
> Lowth supposes, “all the offices and implements, and the whole
> apparatus necessary for the culture of them, and the making of wine;”
> and, doubtless, also serving for the accommodation and defence of the
> labourers; and as places of pleasure for the owners of the vineyards;
> so God provided his church with a most commodious and magnificent
> temple, furnished with all conveniences for every part of that worship
> and service which he required his people to perform to him, and
> affording every requisite accommodation for the residence, support,
> and comfort of the priests and Levites, while ministering in holy
> things, and employed in cultivating God’s mystical vineyard; and where
> he, the Lord of the vineyard, might be peculiarly present, as the
> protector and consolation of his people, their refuge and strength,
> and very present help in times of trouble or danger. Thus the Chaldee
> paraphrast: “I have constituted them the plant of a choice vine, and
> built my sanctuary in the midst of them.” So also Jerome interprets
> the clause.

Thus, the central sanctuary/temple of the Israelites function is a similar vein but in the spiritual realm rather than the physical realm.

Comment: Great, thanks D. Strange that they would call the building a "tower." I guess it was because of the security aspect.

Comment: What do you think about adding the passage I cite here?:  https://www.quora.com/In-Isaiah-5-2-what-is-the-function-of-the-tower-and-how-is-it-prophetically-significant-And-might-it-be-related-to-Isaiah5-8/answer/Bill-Ross-22

Comment: I fully agree that Jesus is alluding to Isaiah's parable.  Jesus uses the parable to as a device to predict the rejection of the Jews and final destruction of the temple by the Romans.  The purpose of the Jesus' parable is different from Isaiah's parable - the latter is to impress the Jews with how much God loved them and cared for them.

Comment: Hmm... I guess then that we don't quite see it the same. Okay, thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator - you are clearly angling for a particular answer

Comment: I'm looking for a more complete and accurate answer.